# Showing $B_X(n)={\rm conj}_G(B_X(n)).$ Is my proof okay?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

This is a [solution-verification](/questions/tagged/solution-verification) question.

### The Details:

Let $G$ be a group and let $X\subseteq G$. Let $n\in\Bbb N$.

Recall that for $H\le G$,

$${\rm conj}_H(X)=\{ hxh^{-1}\mid x\in X, h\in H\}.$$

Define

$$B_X(n)=\bigcup_{k=0}^n\underbrace{{\rm conj}_G(X)^{\pm 1}\dots{\rm conj}_G(X)^{\pm 1}}_{k\text{ times.}}
$$

***Note that the idea here is that each $\pm 1$ is independent of the others.*** For example,

$$\begin{align}
B_X(2)&=\{e\}\cup{\rm conj}_G(X)\cup{\rm conj}_G(X)^{-1}\\
&\cup {\rm conj}_G(X){\rm conj}_G(X)\\
&\cup {\rm conj}_G(X)^{-1}{\rm conj}_G(X)\\
&\cup {\rm conj}_G(X){\rm conj}_G(X)^{-1}\\
&\cup {\rm conj}_G(X)^{-1}{\rm conj}_G(X)^{-1}.
\end{align}$$

> **Lemma:** Let $h\in G$. Then
>
> $$h{\rm conj}_G(X)h^{-1}={\rm conj}_G(X).$$

*Proof:*

We have

$$\begin{align}
h{\rm conj}_G(X)h^{-1}&=h\{ gxg^{-1}\mid x\in X, g\in G\}h^{-1}
\\
&=\{ h(gxg^{-1})h^{-1}\mid x\in X, g\in G\}\\
&=\{ (hg)x(hg)^{-1}\mid x\in X, g\in G\}\\
&=\{ axa^{-1}\mid x\in X, a\in G\}\\
&={\rm conj}_G(X).
\end{align}$$ $\square$

### The Desired Theorem:

> Show $$B_X(n)={\rm conj}_G(B_X(n)).$$

### The Proof in Question:

We have

$$
{\rm conj}_G(B_X(n))=\{ hbh^{-1}\mid b\in B_X(n), h\in G\},
$$

where the RHS is

$$\left\{ hbh^{-1}\,\middle|\, b\in \bigcup_{k=0}^n\underbrace{{\rm conj}_G(X)^{\pm 1}\dots{\rm conj}_G(X)^{\pm 1}}_{k\text{ times.}}, h\in G\right\},\tag{$*$}$$

which gives (and this is where I'm not sure (on the LHS))

$$\begin{align}
\bigcup_{k=0}^n\{ hbh^{-1}\mid b\in{\rm conj}_G(X)^{\pm 1}, h\in G\}^k&=\bigcup_{k=0}^n\left(\bigcup_{h\in G}h{\rm conj}_G(X)^{\pm 1}h^{-1}\right)^k\tag{1}\\
&=\bigcup_{k=0}^n\left(\bigcup_{h\in G}{\rm conj}_G(X)^{\pm 1}\right)^k\tag{Lemma}\\
&=\bigcup_{k=0}^n({\rm conj}_G(X)^{\pm 1})^k\\
&=B_X(n)
\end{align}$$

because $S\cup S=S$ for all sets $S$.

### Context:

As indicated, I'm not sure of the equality between $(*)$ and the LHS of $(1)$. Also, I'm shaky about the equality $(1)$ itself.

*More Context:*

This proof above is my own. I am studying for a postgraduate research degree in linear algebraic groups. The theorem is from a preprint of a paper and its proof is omitted as routine. My supervisor suggested I try it. The kind of answer I'm after is a brief confirmation/disproof of the two areas I mention in the previous section.

*What makes me unsure?*

I'm not sure whether I can pull out the union from the "description part" to the outside of the set builder notation. As for the other part, is the index $\pm 1$ preserved properly?

---

Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assume that $X^{-1}=X$.
Next, for $x,h\in G$ let us denote  $hxh^{-1}=x^h$. It is clear that
$$
(x^g)^h=x^{gh},\ (xy)^h=x^hy^h.
$$

Further your notations are better replaced with ones that tell us what to do:
$$
{\rm conj}_H(X)=X^H
$$

and

$$
B_X(n)=X^G\cup X^GX^G\cup\ldots\cup \underbrace{X^G\ldots X^G}_{n}.
$$

**Lemma.** $(X^G)^h=X^{Gh}=X^G$.

**Theorem.**
$$\begin{align}
B_X(n)^h
&=(X^G\cup X^GX^G\cup\ldots\cup X^G\ldots X^G)^h\\
&=X^{Gh}\cup (X^GX^G)^h\cup\ldots\cup (X^G\ldots X^G)^h\\
&=\ldots
\end{align}$$

This is if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Thank you. Is my proof attempt accurate? This is a [tag:solution-verification] question after all . . .

Comment: Your computation is super accurate, but apparently that's why it's terrible. It's all about notation. As [Halmos](https://entropiesschool.sciencesconf.org/data/How_to_Write_Mathematics.pdf) said "The best notation is no notation".

Comment: Please remind me why we can assume $X^{-1}=X$.

Comment: I replaced $X$ with $X\cup X^{-1}$ to avoid writing $X^{\pm1}$.

Comment: Your proof seems wrong to me then. It's ${\rm conj}_G(X)^{\pm 1}$, not $X^{\pm 1}$. Also, we need to include each case; see my example in the latest edit.

Comment: Of course $(X^G)^{\pm1}\neq X^{\pm1}$. That's not what I claimed. 
But 
$$
(X^G)^{\pm1}=(X^{\pm1})^G=(X\cup X^{-1})^G=X^G\cup (X^{-1})^G.
$$You seem to think that 
$$
X^{\pm G}\cdot X^{\pm G}\neq (X^G\cup X^{-G})(X^G\cup X^{-G}).
$$ So?